# How to get the percentage change from a series of numbers?

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

My requirement is to find a percentage change in a series of numbers (like a trend line). Over the internet, I could find solutions for just finding the percent difference between two numbers but not for a series.

Consider this is the series for 7 days of data: `26, 49, 14, 79, 11, 0, 0`
Now, I need to get either an increase or decrease percent based on the series for those 7 days.

My proposed solution (though I'm not confident about it)

1. Find the percent change between all subsequent two numbers
2. Find the average of all percentage change values from Step 1

Does anyone have a good way to calculate the nearly accurate percentage change? The expected end result is a single value that denotes the overall percentage change in the data trend line that happened in the last 7 days.

Comment: What is your *percentage* based on? If the number changes from `0` to `2`, do you expect the percentage to be `2%`, `200%` or `infinite%`?

Comment: I'd just like to clarify what you're looking for - in your proposed solution, you're generating a scalar value (a single percentage), but earlier in the question you're looking for a trend line (which would be represented as a vector quantity). Are you looking for a single percentage, or a trend line?

Comment: @brads3290 looking for a trend line.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but this should give you a trend line, with the integer indicating percentage increase/decrease between consecutive elements.

I applied your proposed solution too but this solution will be highly affected by outliers (just the nature of a mean).

```js
const list = [26, 49, 14, 79, 11, 0, 0];
let trend = []
for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
  const difference = list[i] - list[i - 1];
  const percentageDifference = difference != 0 ? difference / list[i - 1] * 100 : 0;
  trend.push(percentageDifference);
};
const meanPercentageDifference = trend.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / trend.length;
console.table(trend);
console.log({
  meanPercentageDifference
});
```

Comment: I am a bit new to stackoverflow. 
Did you just lint the code I shared or?

Comment: Thanks, @Bandisa. I'm using a similar solution for now. The only change in my and your solution is considering the highest value as 100 and proportionally changing the rest of the values to have a better consecutive percentage change when some of the values would be greater than 100 in the array.